# Storing resource files as hashmap like structure

Tags: java, file, store

I look at Minecraft directory and found their resources (image, sound, binary-data) store in a way that look like HashMap or like git repository.

Here is the HashMap alike JSON files

[image: HashMap Json]

Here is the actual file system.

[image: Actual File System]

My question is, why would they do that(benefits?), how to do that and what is the correct term for this kind of storing resource file strategies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called B-tree. Pros - Constant lookup time.

Sorry - Very small lookup time. Log(n) to be exact. Thanks Olivier